# kohana 3.1 Request External: POST application/xml doesn't work with native execute

Tags: xml, post, request, kohana, external

I'm trying to perform an external request with Kohana 3.1 with this code in my controller.

```
$request = Request::factory($url);
$request->method(Request::POST);
$request->body($xml);
$request->headers('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
$response = $request->execute();
```

I'm getting this error:

```
HTTP_Exception_500 [ 500 ]: Kohana_HTTP_Header_Value::__construct unknown header value type: integer. array or string allowed.
```

After some research in the code, I found out this was a problem with the function `_native_execute` of the class `Kohana_Request_Client_External`.

This function sets 'content-length' like so:

```
$body = $request->body();
$request->headers('content-length', strlen($body));
```

But `$request->header(...)` expect a string or an array for the second parameter and `strlen` returns an integer.

Is it a bug? I fixed it like this `$request->headers('content-length', (string)strlen($body));`

Then I got another error:

```
ErrorException [ Warning ]: fopen(http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/yyyyy) [<a href='function.fopen'>function.fopen</a>]: failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections
```

This error comes from this line of code `$mode = ($request->method() === HTTP_Request::GET) ? 'r' : 'r+';` again in `_native_execute`.

I forced the value of `$mode` to be `r` and now it works. Is these two errors are bugs or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug and has been fixed in the 3.1/develop branch. It'll be released on the next point release (soon).